# Foreach table row find specific control by ID and its value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to write a function in jQuery which is going through all table rows and searches for hidden field values by specific hidden control ID "hdnIsEmpty", the problem is that I don't know how to do it by this hidden control ID because there are other hidden controls which are not necessarily to touch...
Maybe there is some other way to get what I wan't, but here is my unsuccessful try/approach and the only one I know:

```
<udc:Repeater ID="repDetailedInformation" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("DetailsInformation") %>'>
<table id="tblDetails">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                BLA-BLA-BLA Information
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <udc:HiddenField ID="hdnIsEmpty" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("IsEmpty") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <udc:HiddenField ID="hdnBlaBla" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("BlaBla") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                BLA-BLA-BLA Information
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getHiddenBoolean(name) {
        var selector = 'input:hidden[name$="' + name + '"]';
        var field = $(selector);
        return (field != null && field.length > 0) ? field.val().toLowerCase() == "true" : false;
    };  

    var filteredRows = $('#tblDetails tr td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('#hdnIsEmpty');
    });

    $.each(filteredRows, function () {
        var isEmpty = getHiddenBoolean(filteredRows);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue you have is that ASP.Net Webforms changes the `id` of all `runat="server"` elements at runtime, so you cannot select by them. Even if you could, in this instance you would have duplicates, which is invalid. Instead you could add a `class` to those elements to identify them.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <udc:HiddenField ID="hdnIsEmpty" runat="server" class="hiddenfield" Value='<%#Eval("IsEmpty") %>' />
    </td>
</tr>
```

From there you can just loop over that class selector, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblDetails tr td .hiddenfield').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            // do something here...
        }
    });
});
```

If you are unable to add a `class` attribute on the control, you could instead make the selector more generic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblDetails tr td input:hidden:first').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            // do something here...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah but in "HiddenField" I can't add a class, then I need to write that "HiddenField" to something else and "display: none;"...

Comment: @John sorry, I don't follow what you mean. You can write the value of the hidden field wherever you like from within the `each()` function block. Also, why do you need to set `display: none` on the field - is it not hidden already?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I think he means that the HiddenField does not expose a `class` property.

Comment: ammm... you can't write like this:

<udc:HiddenField ID="hdnIsEmpty" runat="server" class="hiddenfield" Value='<%#Eval("IsEmpty") %>' /> you will get Parser Error

Comment: @ConnorsFan exactly, the `class` property just goes in to the markup, it's not a class in your ASP.Net code.

Comment: @John what are the `<udc: />` controls?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I thought it would work but I get a runtime error if I add a `class` attribute to a HiddenField in the markup.

Comment: Ok, does it generate an `input type="hidden"` in the HTML?

Comment: In that case I updated my answer to give you a more generic alternative

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan BUT (from post).... I don't know how to do it by this hidden control ID because there are other hidden controls which are not necessarily to touch...

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with the control IDs. I specifically avoided them because, as I mentioned, ASP.Net Webforms hacks them around at runtime.

Comment: In order to use the `class` attribute, could @John replace `<udc:HiddenField>` by `<input type="hidden" class="hiddenfield" ... />`? I haven't tested the jQuery selector but, at least, there is no runtime error.

Comment: Ok... this would be a nice option to transform to input and do the magic with class but how about "Eval" attribute, it will support for sure?

Comment: @John - You can try it: `<input id="hdnIsEmpty" runat="server" type="hidden" class="hiddenfield" value='<%# Eval("IsEmpty") %>' />`. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

After taking into account the ASP.NET issue mentioned above, another alternative would be:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var $hidden = $('.tableClass input.hiddenTouchableElements');

  $hidden.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
      // do something here...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: .... I don't know how to do it by this hidden control ID because there are other hidden controls which are not necessarily to touch...

Comment: Then you should change the selector as @Rory to look for a specific hidden class of elements you wish to touch. I'll edit my answer.